# Relation between algebraic and analytic derivations in $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, commutative-algebra, derivations

Let $A,B$ be two $\mathbb R$-algebras. By an $\mathbb R$-linear (algebraic) derivation from $A$ to $B$, we mean a group homomorphism $D:A\rightarrow B$ which contains $\mathbb R$ in its kernel and satisfies the Liebnitz rule, i.e., $D(ab)=aD(b)+bD(a)$ for all $a,b\in A$. Let $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ denote the $\mathbb R$-algebra of all real valued continuous functions defined on $\mathbb R$. If $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous map, we know that $f$ is said to be (analytically) differentiable at $x\in \mathbb R$ if the limit $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}$ exists; and a function which is differentiable at every point of $\mathbb R$ is called a differentiable function. In this case, we denote the derivative of $f$ by $f'$. Let us call an $\mathbb R$-linear algebraic derivation $D:A\rightarrow \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$, where $A$ is an $\mathbb R$-subalgebra of $\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$, to be maximal if there does not exist any $\mathbb R$-subalgebra $A'$, properly containing $A$, and an $\mathbb R$-linear algebraic derivation $D':A'\rightarrow \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ such that $D=D'|_A$. My question is that, if $D:A\rightarrow \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ is a maximal $\mathbb R$-linear algebraic derivation such that $D(x)=1$, where $x:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the identity function, does it follow that $A$ is the ring of real differentiable functions (in the analytic sense), and $D(f)=f'$?

Comment: Shouldn't $D$ be a linear homomorphism instead of a group homomorphism ?

Comment: What does $aD(b)$ mean? $a$ is in $A$ and $D(b)$ is in $B$.

Comment: $D$ is $\mathbb R$-linear. And sorry, i was a little callous in taking arbitrary $A$ and $B$. Actually, in our case, $A$ is a subring of $B$. More generally, to define (algebraic) derivations, one takes $B$ to be an $A$-module.

Comment: OK, the question is too ambitious. The functions $x$ and $e^x$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb R$. So, as $\mathbb R$-algebras, $\mathbb R[x,y]\cong \mathbb R[x,e^x]$, and we can define a derivation $D:\mathbb R[x,e^x] \rightarrow \mathcal C(\mathbb R)$, by setting $D(x):=1$ and $D(e^x)=0$. Using Zorn's lemma, we can extend $D$ to a maximal $\mathbb R$-linear algebraic derivation. But that cannot be the usual differentiation operator. So may be, I should put one further condition that $A$ is the ring of all differentiable functions. Should I cange the question?